# Time complexity for finding k-th minimum element in array using max heapify

Tags: time-complexity, heap

i have given a array (note : it is **not** heap sorted ) and i want to find time complexity of k-th minimum element using max heapify method ?
there are plenty of solutions available for that array which is initially heap sorted ?
but in this case it just a array

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Answer (score 0):

To heapify the first  values has O() time complexity.

To potentially exchange all remaining values with the top-value in that heap (and restore the heap property) has a time complexity of O((-)log).

To read out the top value of that heap (which is the answer) has a time complexity of O(1).

Combined we thus have O( + (-)log)